# Folland Theorem 6.20 (Application Minkowski Inequality Integrals)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I am attempting to understand Folland Theorem 6.20, which uses the Minkowski Inequality for Integrals.  Both are attached below.  I understand up until "Therefore, by Minkowski's Inequality for Integrals..."  However, I do not understand how the given function fulfills the premises of Minkowski or how it is being applied in the line below.

[image]

Thanks!